# Given a symmetrical function, how to solve so symmetrical point lands on $x$?

Tags: calculus, functions

**Say I have the following curve:**

$$y = k_1 + \dfrac{k_2}{1-x} \left\{0\leq x\leq1\right\}$$

**If I say that:**

- $k_1=0.038$
- $k_2=0.002$

**I get this:**
[image]

**How do I?**

a) Find the point of symmetry (somewhere in the red area)?´

b)

1. Pick some $k_1$ (like $0.038$)
2. Pick some $x$ (like $0.9$)
3. Solve for $k_2$, so that the symmetry point lands on $x$?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the point where the derivative of $y(x)$ is either $+1$ or $-1$, meaning the tangent line drawn to the function makes a $45°$ angle with the $x$ axis.

[image: The tangent line makes a 45° angle with the x axis]

So let's calculate the derivative:

$$\begin{align}y(x) &= k_1 + \frac{k_2}{1-x} \\
\Rightarrow y'(x) &= \frac{k_2}{(1-x)^2}\end{align}$$

Let's first find an $x$, such that the derivative is $+1$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k_2}{(1-x)^2} &= 1 \\
k_2 &= (1-x)^2 \\
\pm\sqrt{k_2} &= 1-x \\
x &= 1\pm\sqrt{k_2}
\end{align}$$

These are two solutions, however, since with your condition, $x$ has to be between $0$ and $1$, the only solution is:

$$x = 1 - \sqrt{k_2}$$

Now let's first try to find an $x$, such that the derivative is $-1$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{k_2}{(1-x)^2} &= -1 \\
-k_2 &= (1-x)^2
\end{align}$$

A square number cannot equal a negative number (if we're assuming the function is real), so this time $k_2$ has to be $\le 0$. This will lead to the same solution, but with $-k_2$ instead of $k_2$ under the square root, namely $x = 1 - \sqrt{-k_2}$ (This makes sense if $k_2\le 0$.) Overall the two solutions can be summarized as $x = 1 - \sqrt{|k_2|}$

So the only solution is: $\boxed{x=1-\sqrt{|k_2|}}$. This is where the function's symmetrical point is (or, where the function's tangent line makes a $45°$ angle with the $x$ axis).

With $k_2 = 0.002$, this point happens to be $x\approx0.95528$.

Answer (score 1):

The [curvature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JKCwpxuKPY) of $f(x)=a+\frac b{1-x}$ is:

$$\frac{|f’’(x)|}{((f’(x))^2+1)^\frac32}=\frac{2b|x-1|^3}{((x+1)^4+b^2)^\frac32}$$

Finding the critical values:

$$\frac d{dx}\frac{2b|x-1|^3}{((x+1)^4+b^2)^\frac32}=0\implies\frac{6b(x-1)|x-1|}{((x-1)^4+b^2)^\frac32}=\frac{12b(x-1)^3|x-1|^3}{((x-1)^4+b^2)^\frac52}$$

Cancelling and removing the absolute value since $x\ge0$:

$$(x-1)^4+b^2 =2(x-1)^4$$

We solve to see that, graphically, the maximum curvature is at $\boxed{x=1-\sqrt b,b>0}$. If $b<0$, then the shape of the graph is not like in the question’s picture.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as

$$(1-x)(y-k_1) = k_2$$

This is like $x y = k_2$, except for some changes of coordinates.